# GStreamer pipeline state remains PLAYING even after file has ended

Tags: java, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I'm using a simple GStreamer script and I noticed that the my pipeline is remaining in PLAYING state even after file ended.

```
pipeline = (Pipeline) Gst.parseLaunch(pipelineDescription);
bus = pipeline.getBus();
bus.connect((Bus.EOS) source -> Gst.quit());

//Continuously obtaining state:
new Thread(() -> {
              while(true){
                System.out.println(pipeline.getState());
                try{
                   Thread.sleep(500);
                }catch(Exception e){
                   System.out.println(e);
                }
              }
}).start();


pipeline.play();
Output: PLAYING
Gst.main();
Output: PLAYING
```